# Any way to use class typedef but not include that class's header file?

Tags: c++

Say that I have such a header file (Foo.h):

```
class Foo {
public:
    typedef int Tag;
    // other stuff
}
```

As far as I know, if I want use `Foo::Tag` in other headers, I must `#include "Foo.h"`. Is there any way to avoid including the Foo.h file?

P.S. I don't want to move the `typedef` out of this class's scope.

Comment: You could just copy-paste the headers (the non-code parts)... but that is cheating and brittle. Don't do it (unless all the C++ code is generated)

Comment: Why do you ask, and what is the issue of `#include`-ing the header defining `class Foo`?

Comment: Rather than trying to pull a def *out* of a class without the class, is flipping the logic viable? I.e. outside the class `typedef int MyType;` in a stand-alone `header1.h`, then in this class header you `#include "header1.h` and in this class `typedef MyType Tag;`. Then, the "other" headers you're wishing to avoid pulling in `class.h` can include `header1.h` instead. Otherwise, if you're restricting the decl type to only-and-forever be in this class, you *must* have access to the class *somehow*.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I remember running into this very problem with cyclic dependencies. Forward declaration would be the usual approach, but that is not trivial with nested types, especially for templates with dependent nested types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### No.

If you want to use `Foo::Tag` itself not another type with same name/type, then you have to include the header file.